# eval not evaluating string array into array

Tags: javascript, eval

I have an array of objects that's being passed as a string. I would expect eval to be able to evaluate this into an the real array object, but

```
var arr = '"[{item:1,amount:100,quantity:1},{item:2,amount:200,quantity:2}]"';
console.log(eval(arr));
```

just returns what seems to be a string. Am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: Your string holds a string literal.  It's doing exactly what you told it to.

Comment: @SLaks an array object containing to objects with the properties item, amount, and quantity.

Comment: But that's not what your string holds.  Your string just holds a double-quoted string.

Comment: @SLaks no control over how I receive this element. Did you mean something else?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to do a double eval to get the data as an array

```
var arr = '"[{item:1,amount:100,quantity:1},{item:2,amount:200,quantity:2}]"';
console.log(eval(eval(arr)));
```

Comment: You even might do `JSON.parse()` in the inner call :-)

Comment: *Why is this* Because you have a string inside of the string as the comments above said. Drop the outer quotes and use `JSON.parse()` and tada, it works.

Comment: @thomas What you have in arr is a string holding a js string literal, when you eval it you get the string, this string contains a js array literal when you eval that you get the array.

Comment: @Bergi why would that be preferable?

Comment: @epascarello When I do that I get a syntax error: `"Unexpected token i"`

Comment: @thomas: Less [`eval`-evilness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil) :-) It's not really preferable, you should just use proper [JSON](http://json.org/)

Comment: @Bergi aye, yeah, but I don't have control over how this data is passed to me. I have to make due. Is there a way to change it to JSON without eval, given just this string?

Comment: @thomas: You need to wrap the inner string in parentheses to prevent it from being parsed as a blog.